# React DOM not re-rendering after state change of array property

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-state

I do understand that this problem is very common and most people might find this as a duplicate but I am at my wits end and that is why I am here.

I have a React component called `App` is a functional component.

Start of `App` component

```
function App() {
  
  const [results, setResults] = useState([]);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const [name, setName] = useState('');
  const [isNameSelected, setIsNameSelected] = useState(false);
  ...
```

There is a child component which is acting erratically at the moment and it is part of the return components of the `App` function.

Section of Code in `return` statement of the `App` component:

```
<ListGroup className="typeahead-list-group">
  {!isNameSelected &&
     results.length > 0 &&
     results.map((result: Result) => (
       <ListGroupItem
         key={result.cik}
         className="typeahead-list-group-item"
         onClick={() => onNameSelected(result)}
       >
         {result.cik + ' | ' + result.name}
       </ListGroupItem>
     ))}
</ListGroup>
```

A change to to `results` is handled by the component `FormControl`'s `onChange` function here also part of the `return` statement of `App`:

```
<FormControl
  placeholder="Entity/CIK"
  id="searchInput"
  type="text"
  autoComplete="off"
  onChange={handleInputChange}
  value={name}
/>
```

`handleInputChange` is defined in `App` function as:

```
const handleInputChange = (e: any) => { // Triggers when search bar is changed
  // remove error bubble
  setAlertMessage(new AlertData('', false));
  const nameValue = e.target.value; // get the new input
  setName(nameValue); // set the new input
  // even if we've selected already an item from the list, we should reset it since it's been changed
  setIsNameSelected(false);
  setResults([]); // clean previous results
  if (nameValue.length > 1) { // if the input is more than 1 character
    setIsLoading(true); // set loading to true
    updateSearchInput(nameValue)  // get the results
      .then((res) => {
        setResults(res as React.SetStateAction<never[]>); // set the results
        setIsLoading(false); // set loading to false
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        // error bubble
        let strError = error.message;
        strError = strError.split(':').pop();
        let errorMessage: AlertData = new AlertData(strError, true); // create error message for empty search
        setAlertMessage(errorMessage); // set alert message
        // loading spinner
        setIsLoading(false);
      });
  }
}
```

However when there is an input change in form control, like typing in an entire word, the search functionality works, populating the DOM with suggested words. However when I clear the value in `FormControl` really fast (by pressing Backspace/Delete several times in quick succession), then the search results stay. Doing it slow or selecting and clearing it all at once however does not show this erratic behavior.

I have used `console.log` to print out the value of `results` in the an empty component like this:

```
{console.log(results) && (<div><div/>)}
```

in `return` statement of App to see what the contents of `results` are. However it does show that `results` value were not updated by  `setResults()`.

This problem however does not exist for the other states utilized here. Why?

**EDIT**

From the answer accepted below from [@ghybs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5108796/ghybshttps://). This is a timeline of what might be happening with the call:

1. Enter search
2. `await` call runs but request response is slow so takes a while.
3. Delete all the keyword in search
4. `results` is made empty with `setResults([])` in `handleInputChange` call.
5. await call finishes. `setResults(res as React.SetStateAction<never[]>)` runs making `results` non-empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You very probably just have plenty concurrent requests (1 per key stroke, including back space?), and unordered results from your `updateSearchInput` async function: the last received one overwrites your `results`, but that one may not originate from your last key stroke (the one that removed the last character from your textarea).

Typically if an empty search is faster than a search with plenty words, the results from empty input do clear your `results`, but then these are filled again by the results of a previous search.

Comment: Oh a data race issue! The search does take a while. What might be happening is this: 
1. Enter search
2. `await` call runs but request response is slow so takes a while.
3. Delete all the keyword in search
4. `results` is made empty with `setResults([])` call
5. await call finishes. `setResults(res as React.SetStateAction<never[]>)` runs.

A data race problem. I would add this to the original comment for better clarification of answer.